# Apex Class IF Statement Has No Code Coverage

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have a simple apex class that updates the passwords for some shared Users with specific names. The test class is not covering the if statement. What do I need to change to get more than 40% code coverage in my dev environment?

```
public class UpdatePassword {
    public UpdatePassword()
    {
        //Get a list of volunteer users
        List<User> userList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
                               FROM User
                               WHERE Email = 'sampleUser@gmail.com' 
                               AND (LastName = 'Cisneros' OR LastName = 'Lopez' OR LastName = 'Ingram')]; 
        //Set passwords
        for(User u : userList){
            if(u.LastName == 'Cisneros'){            
                System.setPassword(u.Id, 'Cisneros123');
            }            
            if(u.LastName == 'Lopez'){            
                System.setPassword(u.Id, 'Lopez123');
            }
            if(u.LastName == 'Ingram'){            
                System.setPassword(u.Id, 'Ingram123');
            }
        }
        update userList;
    }
}
```

Updated test class to insert 3 users:

```
@isTest
private class UpdateWPassword_Test {
    
    //Insert test users 
    @isTest
    static void insertUsers(){
        UpdatePassword changepwd = new UpdatePassword(); 
        List<User> userList = new List<User>();
        
        //Add users
          userList.add(new User (Lastname = 'Cisneros',
                alias = 'Cuser', 
                email = 'sampleUser@gmail.com', 
                username = 'cisnerosuser@gmail.com.wm',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = '00e4x000000q33YAAQ',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago'       
           ));
            userList.add(new User (Lastname = 'Lopez',
                alias = 'Luser', 
                email = 'sampleUser@gmail.com', 
                username = 'lopezuser@gmail.com.wm',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = '00e4x000000q33YAAQ',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago'       
           ));
           userList.add(new User (Lastname = 'Ingram',
                alias = 'Iuser', 
                email = 'sampleUser@gmail.com', 
                username = 'ingramuser@gmail.com.wm',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = '00e4x000000q33YAAQ',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago'       
           ));
        Test.startTest();
          insert userList;
        Test.stopTest();        
        System.debug('User List: ' + userList);
        
        //Assert for user lastname
          userList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
                      FROM User
                      WHERE Email = 'sampleUser@gmail.com' 
                      AND LastName = 'Lopez'];
        
            for(User u : userList){             
                System.assertEquals('Lopez', u.LastName);                
            }      
    }    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've changed it so that the names are different, but the reason that those lines aren't getting coverage is because the Users that your creating in your test class don't have those last names. You're iterating over `userList`, but that list is empty in your test class because your test users have different last names. In order to get coverage for the whole class, you'll need to create a user with each last name in the test class.

Comment: so do I need to create 3 seperate test methods for each lastname?

Comment: You can create one method, but you'll need to insert three users.

Comment: I updated the test class to insert the 3 users to match what's in the class, but there is still no code coverage for the IF statement.

Comment: You're SOQL query also has an email filter and your test users don't have the same email so you query still isn't returning any records.

Comment: All the shared user accounts have the same email, so I updated the test class users to have the same email and I'm still at 40% code coverage. I pushed both classes to prod, ran the test and shockingly I got 100% code coverage!! Wasn't expecting that. Anyway, thanks for all your suggestions. I learned a lot today.

Answer (score 1):

You have to meet the criteria for the if statements (last names of the users being Johnson, Martin and Ingram), and so you must have test cases where your test users have those last names or you won't get full code coverage.